# Обьясните пару мест в коде...

Tags: c++

Есть код, и пара мест, где я не совсем ориентируюсь:

```
class myclass{
public:
    int sum;
    int mum;
    void sum_it(int x);
};

void myclass::sum_it(int x){
    int i;

    sum = 0;
    for(i=x; i; i--) sum+=i;
}

int main()
{
    int myclass::*dp;//1 указатель на класс???
    void (myclass::*fp)(int x);//2 указатель на класс, каким образом, через что передается х????
    myclass c;

    dp = &myclass::sum;//ссылки
    fp = &myclass::sum_it;//

    (c.*fp)(7);//А вот это я совсем плохо понял...(
    cout << "Summation of 7 is " << c.*dp;// c.*dp;-это тоже плохо понимаю(
    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Обьясните на пальцах как это работает...
Спасибо.

Comment: а Вы пробовали компилировать этот код?

Comment: Конечно, он работает...

Comment: Сейчас разбираюсь, и не совсем понимаю (зачем .* и ->* вообще нужно...). Можно же и без них всё сделать...

Comment: я имел в виду компилировать и запускать, чтобы посмотреть, что он делает.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class myclass{
public:
    int sum;
    int mum;
    void sum_it(int x);
};

void myclass::sum_it(int x){
    int i;
    sum = 0;
    for(i=x; i; i--) sum+=i;
}

int main()
{
    int myclass::*dp; // числовая ссылка которая сейчас никуда не указывает.

    void (myclass::*fp)(int x);
    myclass c;

    dp = &myclass::sum; // тут привязка dp к сумме в классе
    fp = &myclass::sum_it; // ссылка на функцию sum_it

    (c.*fp)(50); // c - класс. вызов функции sum_it через ссылку fp с передачей числа 7
    cout << "Summation of 7 is " << c.*dp << endl;// c.*dp - это ссылка в сумме класса
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`dp` — указатель на int.

`dp = &myclass::sum;` — присвоить адрес `myclass::sum;` переменной `dp`.

`fp` — указатель на функцию, которая принимает int и возвращает ничего (`void`).

`(c.*fp)(7);` — вызвать функцию на которую указывает `fp` от аргумента `7`.

Насколько я понял, такая конструкция позволяет хранить относительный адрес поля/метода в классе.